# React: Utilising QuerySelectorAll in Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What would be the best way of incorporating this JS code with React?

```js
  document.querySelectorAll(".servicesaffectedtag").forEach((tag) => {
    tag.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
      tag.classList.toggle("active-tag");
    });
  });
```

Is this something that would need to go into the `ComponentDidMount()` function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using querySelectorAll() and addEventListener() would be the way you'd do things if you weren't using React. In React, you should be defining event behaviour within your render() method

Answer (score 1):

In react, you can refer to elements using refs. (https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

However, a better solution would be putting an onClick listener on each element, and changing the class based on state with the ternary operator (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) like this:

```
<tag 
onClick={() => { classActive ? setClassActive(false) : setClassActive(true) }} className={classActive ? "active-tag" : "" }
>
</tag>
```

Comment: Thanks Simon! Any idea on what the state would look like?